# How to download files with filename containing special characters using .Net WebClient

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting an error “400 – Bad Request”  while using .Net WebClient to download files with filename containing certain characters:

For example if the file is named: `5L1XQE6FTest #.mp4`; this generates an error.

If I remove the `#` sign the file is downloaded fine:

Here is my code:

```
public ActionResult DownloadVideoFile(string filepath)
{
    try
    {              
        filepath = "http://localhost:1832/VideoUploads/" + filepath;
        var type = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        var path = Path.GetFileName(filepath);

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {           
            var buffer = client.DownloadData(filepath);
            return File(buffer, type.ToString(), path);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var test = e.Message;
    }

    return null;    
}
```

I have no  control over the filename that I am trying to download as files are user submitted.

When I Url encode the file I get a "Cannot find file" error:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    filepath = Url.Encode(filepath);
    var buffer = client.DownloadData(filepath);
    return File(buffer, type.ToString(), path);
}
```

Here is the path after URL encoding:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a1832%2fVideoUploads%2f5L1XQE6FTest+%23.mp4'

How can I resolve the Bad Request error while downloading files with special or reserved characters?

Answer (score 1):

At what point in your code is the exception actually being raised? `WebClient` should have no problem downloading any validly named resource (valid as in it actually functions as a URL). If the URL you're trying to use is in fact *not* a valid URL (because of the odd file name), URL encoding it might be sufficient to fix the issue.

However, you're also using the bad file name later as a parameter to `File`, and that's probably a bad idea. If this is where the exception is being raised, simply constructing your own filename, without the problematic characters, should be enough to solve the problem.

Comment: The exception is thrown here: var buffer = client.DownloadData(filepath); The filename being sent to the webclient is exactly : 5L1XQE6FTest #.mp4

Comment: Try urlencoding just the filename bit before you concat it to the rest of the URL.

Comment: I URL encoded the filepath just before the client downloads: Error:Could not find file" filepath = Url.Encode(filepath);
                    var buffer = client.DownloadData(filepath);

Comment: First, don't encode the whole URL, just the filename part. Second, you're somehow getting an actual filesystem path in there. You need to get rid of all the `C:\...` jazz.

Answer (score 1):

Please replace # with %23 it would work.